# ¿Cómo llevar a producción una aplicación con React y NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, api, express

hace bastante tiempo tengo la duda de cuál es la mejor opción para llevar a producción una aplicación web que utilize ReactJS y NodeJS como API.
¿Tengo que subir las dos aplicaciones al mismo servidor o van separadas?

Comment: Tu pregunta es basada en opiniones, motivo por el cual terminará cerrada. De todas formas no hay nada (más allá del desempeño o la seguridad) que te impida usar el mismo servidor o servidores diferentes. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás empezando en un proyecto, o en general es un proyecto pequeño, no hay problema en dejar ambas cosas funcionando en un mismo servidor.
Ahora, si eventualmente necesitas escalar quizás porque han aumentado tu cuota de usuario, en general es buena práctica separar estos entornos. Puede que tus assets, entre ellos los archivos js, quieras dejarlos en un CDN para mejor disponibilidad a nivel mundial, menor latencia, etc, aparte que en general es más barato el precio por byte ocupado en comparación a un servidor dedicado, que es donde tendrías corriendo tu app NodeJS (esto es relativo, ya que en primera instancia estarías pagando por dos servicios en vez de uno, pero a la larga tiende a ser más barato).
En fin, si te estás iniciando con node/react o si no has llegado a tener problemas donde escalar sea la solución, te sugiero no te preocupes por estos aspectos aún.

Comment: Lo cual es una opinión y no un hecho probado. La pregunta se basa en opiniones, y la tuya es válida como la de cualquier otra respuesta. Evitemos responder preguntas basadas en opiniones. Saludos